# How do I calculate the moment of the solstice?

Tags: observational-astronomy, the-sun, astropy, solstice

I'm trying to calculate the moment of the upcoming summer solstice using astropy, and I can't seem to get an answer that matches the accepted values that I see online. I thought that the moment of the solstice would be when the Sun has maximum/minimum declination, but according to my plot below that moment is at about `2023-06-21 23:00 UTC` instead of `2023-06-21 14:58 UTC` according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_solstice). Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import astropy.time
import astropy.coordinates
import astropy.visualization
import numpy as np

astropy.coordinates.solar_system_ephemeris.set("de440")

astropy.visualization.quantity_support()
astropy.visualization.time_support()

time = np.linspace(astropy.time.Time("2023-06-21"), astropy.time.Time("2023-06-22"), num=1000)

sun = astropy.coordinates.get_body("sun", time=time)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(time, sun.dec)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Horizons agrees with Wikipedia https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=YES&COMMAND=10&EPHEM_TYPE=OBSERVER&CENTER=500%40399&START_TIME=%272023-Jun-21+12%3A00%27&STOP_TIME=%272023-Jun-21+18%3A00%27&STEP_SIZE=1h&QUANTITIES=%271%2C2%2C31%27&ANG_FORMAT=DEG&APPARENT=AIRLESS&OBJ_DATA=NO You need the apparent RA & declination, rather than the astrometric.

Comment: Also, the instant of the solstice is when the Sun's ecliptic longitude is 90 degrees.  It will be slightly different than when the maximun declination is reached.

Comment: Man it's tempting to link this question into flat earth circles

Answer (score 7):

Per [@PM 2Ring's comment](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/118753?noredirect=1), I needed to use apparent RA/declination rather than GCRS (which is the default returned by `astropy.coordinates.get_body`). In astropy, this is implemented as the [True Equator True Equinox](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.TETE.html#astropy.coordinates.TETE) coordinate system.

Also, @GregMiller points out that the instant of the summer solstice is the moment that the Sun's ecliptic longitude is 90 degrees, not when declination reaches a maximum.

Incorporating both of those helpful comments leads to this script:

```
import scipy.optimize
import astropy.units as u
import astropy.time
import astropy.coordinates

astropy.coordinates.solar_system_ephemeris.set("de441_part-2")

time_solstice = astropy.time.Time(
    scipy.optimize.root_scalar(
        f=lambda t: (astropy.coordinates.get_body("sun", time=astropy.time.Time(t, format="unix")).tete.ra - 90 * u.deg).value,
        bracket=[
            astropy.time.Time("2023-06-20").unix,
            astropy.time.Time("2023-06-23").unix,
        ],
    ).root,
    format="unix",
)

print(time_solstice.iso)
```

which prints:

```
2023-06-21 14:57:49.087
```

This rounds to the same value as wikipedia.